# pass $index as a parameter from directive template to directive's controller and use module controller's function in directive controller's function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

> Here i am using *personManager* as a controller and *myPersonDirective* as directive.

- <strike>How can i pass ***$index*** from template to deletePerson() function.</strike>
- How can i use ***personManageInst.person*** in deletePerson(index) to perform splice() function on it.

> ### myDirective.js
>
> ```
> var myDirModule = angular.module('myDirApp', []);
> var personManager = function()
> {
>    var personManageInst = this;
>    personManageInst.personsData = [
>        {name: "Sam", age:33, city:"Delhi"},
>        {name: "Mac", age:22, city:"Mumbai"},
>    ];
>    personManageInst.addNewMember = function()
>    {
>        personManageInst.personsData.push({name: personManageInst.name, age: personManageInst.age, city: personManageInst.city});      
>    };
> };
> var myPersonDirective = function()
> {
>   return{
>     restrict: "AE",
>     templateUrl: "personsTemplate.html",
>     scope: {
>         pers: "=",
>         index: "@"
>     },
>     controller: function($scope){
>         $scope.deletePerson = function(index)
>         {
>             console.log(index);     output: index no.
>             personManageInst.personsData.splice(index, 1); //output: personManageInst is undefined
>         };
>     }
> }
> };
> myDirModule.controller("myPerCont", personManager).directive("personDir", myPersonDirective);
> ```
>
> ### personsTemplate.html
>
> ```
> <tr>
>    <td>{{pers.name}}</td>
>    <td>{{pers.age}}</td>
>    <td>{{pers.city}}</td>
>    <td>
>     <button type="button" ng-click="deletePerson(index)">Delete</button>
>    </td>
> </tr>
> ```
>
> ### myApp.html
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>    <head>add title, css, scripts</head>
> </html>
> <body>
>    .
>    .
>    .
>    <tr person_dir pers="perso" index="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="perso in personManageInst.personsData"></tr>
>    .
>    .
> </body>
> ```

Comment: Your deletePerson function must be into the controller

Answer (score 0):

Your deletePerson function should be in controller. The ng-repeat needs to be -'track by $index', and then you can call the function.